# Using Priority Queue to return the middle value in Java

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

I'm currently stuck on a problem, let's say I want to find the middle value the user inputted, is there a function in Java wherein I can *peek* or *return* the middle value?

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class PQueue {

    public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr;

        PriorityQueue<Integer> queueB = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        for(int j=0; j<=4; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Input Intergers: ");
            arr = console.nextInt();
            queueB.add(arr);
        }
        System.out.print(queueB.peek());    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a priority queue? What do you mean by middle value?

Comment: Oh come on people. The question is perfectly clear.

Comment: @Falmarri I'm using Priority Queue so that it'll sort the inputted integers beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Just pop half the values off the PQ. The last one popped is the middle one.

The case where *N* is even is left as an exercise for the reader.

Of course this is assuming that by 'middle' you mean 'median'. If you mean 'mean', you're using the wrong data structure: you should use an array, sort it, and evaluate `(array[0]+array[last])/2`.

Comment: You can just get the smallest and largest values in O(n) time.

Comment: Or you can use a variant of Quicksort to determine the median.

Comment: `(array[0]+array[last])/2` That's not the mean